# Horizontally center align block element

Tags: css

I think lots of people like me keep doing it like this:

```
html {
    text-align: center;
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ofpy7mgz/

I don't even remember why we add `text-align: center;` to the parent element, must be for browser compatibility? Well, is it safe to simply drop that now days?

**Edit**: The goal is just for center aligning `<body>` element, not for any text alignment etc.

Comment: We add `text-align: center;` to the parent only if the children (the body in this case) is being displayed as inline-level elements. In other words, it has no effect on block-level elements. Therefore you can remove that in this particular instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because IE6 (and the older ones + I think IE7 in quirk mode) centered all elements (both `block` and `inline`) by this way, `margin: auto` didn't work there.

Other browsers (`non-IE`) wasn't able to center block elements by `text-align: center;`. They used, as a specification said, `text-align: center` for `inline` elements, `margin: auto` for `block` elements.

You can remove that if you don't want to support IE6.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like use your code, more simply:

```css
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>hello world.</p>
```